# QGIS 2.99.0-149 modeler inputs Feature Source vs. Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.99.0 modeler, there is a obviously a new input type called *Feature Source*, wich does what *Vector Layer* did in previous versions (but *Vector Layer* is still available):

[image]

New behaviour, as can be seen so far:

- *Vector Layer* can not be restricted to certain shape types and is not recognized as algorithm input.
- *Feature Source* can be restricted to shape types and is recognized as algorithm input (successor to *Vector Layer*)

The auld *Vector Layer* input in QGIS 2.14. etc. modeler:

[image]

The new *Vector Layer* input in QGIS 2.99.0:

[image]

The new *Feature Source* input in QGIS 2.99.0:

[image]

**Question:** What is the difference between the new *Vector Layer* and *Feature Source*, provided *Feature Source* is not restricted to a certain shape type? And if *Vector Layer* inputs do not appear in algorithm input selections, what is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's just a change in naming convention as defined in [ModelerParameterDefinitionDialog.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/modeler/ModelerParameterDefinitionDialog.py#L65).

```
QGIS < v2.99  |  QGIS >= v2.99
------------------------------
Table         |  Vector Layer
Vector Layer  |  Feature Source
```

Comment: It's not obvious according to me. I would prefer the old terminology. And the algorithm `Add field to attribute table` doesn't accept a `vector layer` for instance, so it's exactly a table input.

Comment: @Gustry - I understand what you mean. Naming it _Feature Source_ is very similar to what ArcGIS use: [Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/feature-class-basics.htm). Wonder if this played any influence... :)

Comment: In 2.99.0-151 they exposed all layer type filters to model feature source, vector layer and multi layer inputs. Now we can obviously use feature source OR vector layer as algorithm input. Now totally confusing to me, why the distinction between feature source and vector layer? https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17030

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Guess they forgot ;)

Comment: It's not that simple. A vector layer parameter will ONLY accept vector layers. Some algorithms restrict their input types to vector layer parameters, because those algorithms only make sense for layers (e.g. the "select by..." algorithms, or algorithms which modify a table in place like Truncate). But feature sources don't have to be a layer. They can be ANY input type which has features. Many of the benefits of feature sources won't become evident until 3.2 or greater, but in 3.0 the biggest difference is that a "feature source" input allows you to operate an algorithm on a selected subset.

Comment: @ndawson - Could you post your comment as an answer please so that I can delete mine? I want to avoid any confusion my post may cause :)